# Rails static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, assets

In Rails 3.1 world, where is the recommended location for static assets that don't require precompilation or preprocessing (such as fonts and images)? The current Rails documentation is a little unclear about whether they "should" be placed in the "right" location (`app/assets/font`, `app/assets/images`, etc.) or whether placing them directly in `public/assets` is acceptable.

(note #1: I'm aware of [Rails 4 static assets in public/ or app/assets/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135841/rails-4-static-assets-in-public-or-app-assets), but it's a) Rails 4 specific and b) has only one answer which I don't find convincing.)

(note #2: I'm asking this question because I'm looking for ways to speed up asset precompilation - I'd welcome answers in that context.)

Answer (score 2):

From Asset Pipeline documentation

> Assets can still be placed in the public hierarchy. Any assets under
>   public will be served as static files by the application or web
>   server. You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some
>   pre-processing before they are served.

More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline)